# ua_session_id set to 'non_interaction': true to fix low bounce rate but bounce rate is steady at 4%

Tags: google-analytics

We are working with Qualtrics to gather feedback from our users. When we implemented the code, their session_id (ev_session_id) caused our bounce rate to plummet to 4%. In one day, the ev_session_id accounted for 84% of the total events. We discussed with Qualtrics and they updated their code to this:

```
gtag('event', 'ev_session_id', {
           'ua_session_id': sessionId,
           'non_interaction': true
       });
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work. We are preparing to discuss with their POC but we wanted to gather some more information first.

Is this a behavior that should be expected from "'non-interaction': true"? Do any of you have an opinion to this implementation or have any recommendations?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to send non interaction event the syntax is that.